# Event listener if div is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

In some AJAX query, in response.done I refresh some div and it works fine, the problem is this refresh doesn't refresh also another function(this function fill the content `html()` of another div inside the refreshed one). I'm thinking for a trick to add an **event** to listen when that div is reloaded, I lunch my `getAmount()` function.

I tried to add that function after reloading part in AJAX but it doesn't work.

**file1.phtml**

```
ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
...
ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    jQuery("#shopping-cart-table").load(location.href + " #shopping-cart-table"); //Here I reload my div.
});
```

**file2.phtml**

```
function getAmount() {
    var some = jQuery(this).attr('data-subtotal');
    jQuery('#shopping-cart-table .data').each(function(){
        jQuery('.ship-cart-vendor-header').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).find('.not-reached').html(some);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You may probably want to listen to the DOM changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom.

Comment: If you are listening for changes inside the replaced dom, then your event wont get a hit. It seems like what you want to do is bad practice. I think you should replace the element in the dom and then call the event in the .done functioner. Otherwise you could add $('body').on('change', '.yourElementClass', function(){ ... do something here ... });

Comment: You are calling `load` inside an `ajax` success-handler. This will result in two requests sent to the server. Can't you directly use the first AJAX-response?

Comment: @feeela I didn"t understand your question

Comment: @Martin M this: `var priceed = jQuery(".price").html(); $('body').on('change', priceed, function(){ alert('changed');});` doesn't work

Comment: @prc What is in the `response` of the first AJAX request? Why do you execute two requests to the server?

Comment: @feeela because in my ajax url I call some controller who returns me the html page updated, this is why I have to update the content to get the new one

Answer (score 0):

You've to call your `getAmount` function in the `load` callback, what mean after the complete reloading :

```
jQuery("#shopping-cart-table").load(location.href + " #shopping-cart-table", function(){
    getAmount();
});
```

Comment: I have already tested it but it doesn't work, in this case, I must wait when loading div is finished and after that I lunch `getAmount();` Im not able to detect when the load action div is finished !